# Function for regular expression in R

Tags: r

I need to extract certain sequences from a string of text. 
Something like 93085k82 will be embedded in text.
Is there a script that identify when 5 numbers, a letter, and then 2 numbers occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use pattern starting with word boundary (`\\b`) followed by five digits (`\\d{5}`), a lower case letter (`[a-z]{1}`) and two digits (`\\d{2}`) followed by the word boundary (`\\b`)

```
grep("\\b\\d{5}[a-z]{1}\\d{2}\\b", v1)
```

If we need to extract

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(v1, "\\b\\d{5}[a-z]{1}\\d{2}\\b")
```